# CSS svg contents won't scale

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created a vector image in Illustrator CS6 which I want to embed directly into an HTML page. I save it as an SVG and click "SVG code" to retrieve code that looks like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="623.4px" height="39.7px" viewBox="0 0 623.4 39.7" enable-background="new 0 0 623.4 39.7" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M12.5,40.4c-5.3,0-9.2-1.8-12.2-6l5.2-4.7c1.6,2,4.2,3.5,6.2,3.5c2.7,0,5-2,5-4.3c0-2.1-1.4-4.1-4....... [ LOT OF PATHS ETC ETC ]
</svg>
```

I can change the size of the svg box with css, but the contents don't change size. I want them to scale proportionally so that I can set the image to the full height of the container. How do I do this? I'm trying avoid javascript.

Here's a diagram of what's happening:

```
_____________________________________
|                                   |
| small design here                 |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   | <--empty space "booo"
|                                   |
_____________________________________
```

Comment: I don't really think css would help here. You will need to zoom the svg to fill in that box.

Comment: Do you just need to add preserveAspectRatio="none" as an attribute of the `<svg>` element?

Comment: @abhitalks are you saying it is not possible to replicate the behavior of an svg image?

Comment: @Robert I do want to preserve the aspect ratio. I want the svg to act like a block element

Comment: But it is a block element. Perhaps you should create a jsfiddle as I don't really understand the question as written.

Comment: The contents of the svg do not scale with its bounding box. So scaling effectively just creates extra padding.

Answer (score 0):

By the way did you try:

```
.svgzoom {
    zoom: 200%; 
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tJu6n/

May not work in Firefox though. You may have to try transform scale perhaps there.

Comment: I'm not sure his this relates to my question.